# eclipse plugin set encoding in code

Tags: java, eclipse, encoding, utf-8, eclipse-plugin

How can I set the encoding of workbench in from code?

I know the way of **Window -> Preferences -> General -> Workspace**, but my users are probably not familiar with Eclipse and I want to preset the encoding to UTF-8, because my eclipse application deals with all kinds of languages and can only be encoded with UTF-8.

I saw something like `ResourcesPlugin.getEncoding()`, but I can't set it. Is there any way I can do it so that when users open the eclipse, the encoding is already set to UTF-8?

Edit:

This should work

```
IScopeContext projectScope = new ProjectScope(project);
  IEclipsePreferences projectNode = projectScope.getNode("org.eclipse.core.resources");
  projectNode.node("encoding").put("<project>", "UTF-8");
  try {
    projectNode.flush();
  } catch (BackingStoreException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Comment: I currently don't have time to write a complete and useful answer, but have a look at this article: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipsePreferences/article.html#preferences_plugin.ini I think you'll want to set `org.eclipse.core.resources/encoding=UTF-8` and/or `org.eclipse.core.runtime/content-types/org.eclipse.jdt.core.javaProperties/charset=UTF-8`.

Comment: Hi Marvin, thank you for the hint. I tried it but it didn't work, could you help me point out what's wrong? see my edited post.

Comment: oki I got it. Thank you!